# Using Intel Ivy Bridge GPU for triple monitor setup

Tags: intel-core-i5, multiple-monitors, ivy-bridge

I am planning to upgrade my CPU to an Intel Core i5-3450 (Ivy Bridge).  However, my motherboard (ASRock B75M Micro ATX Motherboard) does not have an onboard video chipset.  Will I still be able to take advantage of the Ivy Bridge's integrated GPU using the motherboard's DVI or VGA ports?  My goal is to run a triple monitor setup with two monitors connected to a dedicated graphics card and a third connected to the motherboard.  Will this be possible with the motherboard I have mentioned?